# How to convert an image into base 64 format in kendo imagebrowser

Tags: javascript, c#, kendo-ui, telerik

I am using Kendo version Kendo.Mvc, Version=2015.2.902.545

I want to convert the my image into **Base64** format in kendo EditorFor,
But it does not support URLHandler in the above version.
below is the script and kendo image browser

Kendo Image Browser Code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().EditorFor(model => model.Text)
    .Name(Model.Name)
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%; height:200px", id = Model.Id })
    .ImageBrowser(imageBrowser => imageBrowser
    .Image("~/Content/UserFiles/Images/{0}")
    .Read("Read", "ImageBrowser")
    .Create("Create", "ImageBrowser")
    .Destroy("Destroy", "ImageBrowser")
    .Upload("Upload", "ImageBrowser")
    .Thumbnail("Thumbnail", "ImageBrowser"))
    .Events(e => e.Change(changedEventName))
    .Encode(false)
    .Tools(tool => tool.ViewHtml())
    //.Tools(tool => tool.FontSize())
    //.Tools(tool => tool.FontName())
    // Oliver added on 27 June 2018. To enable the subscript and superscript function
    .Tools(tool => tool.SubScript())
    .Tools(tool => tool.SuperScript())
    .Tools(tool => tool.FontColor())                                                            
    .StyleSheets(s => s.Add("/Content/KendoEditorStyle.css"))
)
```

Script:

```
<script>
function imageUrlFn(path) {
    var result = "";
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: "/ImageBrowser/GetImage",
        data: {
            path: path
        },
        success: function (data) {
            result = data;
        }
    });

    return result;
}
</script>
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult GetImage(string path)
{
    Byte[] currentFile = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath(Path.Combine(contentFolderRoot, "UserFiles", imagesFolder) + path));

    if (currentFile == null) return HttpNotFound();

    String file = Convert.ToBase64String(currentFile);
    return Json("data:image/png;base64," + file, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I need help for the following problem like how to pass function in the image browser as it does not take .CustomButton also or anything like an event when clicking on insert button which get pop up when we select image icon.

*Thanks & Regards Tejas*